# Which is better to use in Laravel 5.2 redirection?

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am newbie in Laravel and I am using Version 5.2, and I wanna know what is better to use in return value on redirecting routes in my Controller.

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

or

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

Please indicate your source(s) in there are any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michel , thats the same; as you already know
so use whatever you are comfortable with,

but i think there are no performance boost or security risks or whatever you might be afraid of. 
Those are static functions.

Some says that you should not use a facade but thats wrong. unless you realy mess things up

You can find more informations about it here , writen by the creator of laravel

[HERE](http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/)

Comment: glad for you mate : D

Answer (score 1):

Both [`redirect()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-redirect) helper and [`Redirect`](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Redirect.html) facade do the same thing — they return the [Redirector](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.html) instance. So it's just the matter of your convenience.

I personally prefer using the helper, as shown in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#redirects).

Answer (score 1):

It is totally depends on your preference.You can call name `route` with below way also:

```
return redirect(route('home'));
```

or

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('home');
```

I personally prefer first one.

Answer (score 0):

It's about your preferences, because these are just shortcuts and **both do exactly the same**. Personally I prefer to use helpers instead of facades.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Move away from Facades.

Ultimately both will give you the desired outcome because the Laravel IoC container will resolve them to the same underlying class.

Many people prefer Facades for visual appeal.

If this does not apply to you, **consider code explicitness and modularity**.

> Constructor injection means that a class’ dependencies are injected via the constructor when that class is created. It is an explicit declaration of what that class needs, and therefore gives an idea as to what that class does.

Source: Taylor Otwell (creator of Laravel) blog post [Response: Don't Use Facades](http://taylorotwell.com/response-dont-use-facades/)

> with Laravel 5, we have illuminate/contracts and method injection. This makes it significantly easier to achieve the same end result as a facade would, while also decoupling our code in the process.

Source: Jeffrey Way (creator of laracasts) forum response [To use or not to use Facades?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/to-use-or-not-to-use-facades?page=1)

Comment: This was useful as it was stated by Taylor Otwell. Nice Qevo!